# SQL Command to include a random row from the table

Tags: sql, random

I have this code that allows me to select a user from the database, and only limit them to 1,
yet how do I pick a random user from the SQL database?
many thanks.

```
SELECT username FROM books LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The canonical solution in MySQL is:

```
SELECT username 
FROM books 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```

However, sorting tables can be *very* expensive.  If you have a large table, then something like this might be much faster:

```
SELECT username
FROM books b CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM books b) bb
WHERE rand() < 100 / cnt
ORDER BY rand()
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Wow Gordon! What you do is simply extraordinary. With current rate you will be in **TOP 3 SO all-the-time users this week** (I know you won't stop until you become No.1 and I really wait for that moment. I hope one day we will have opportunity to meet in person)

Answer (score 1):

**For Mysql**

The most simple thing you can do is ORDER BY RAND().  However, this is a slow operation for large tables. As this would involve a full table scan.

```
SELECT username 
FROM books 
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1;
```